# Java. Reading 2 Dimensional array in a file (notepad)

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans

example i have this numbers or arrays on my file (notepad)

2 3 4 5 7 2 6 2

2 4 6 8 9 4 8 1

I want to ask if how to read the next row. I can only read the first row using this code.

> 

```
    String path = "/path/notepad.txt";

    String stringOfNumbers[];

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader (new FileReader(path));

    String lineOfNumbers = br2.readLine();

    stringOfNumbers = lineOfNumbers.split(" ");
  //stringOfNumbers = lineOfNumbers.split("\n");
    String str = lineOfNumbers.replace(","," ");
    System.out.println(str);
    System.out.print("");


    int numbers[][] = new int [stringOfNumbers.length][stringOfNumbers.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
    {
        numbers[i][i] = Integer.parseInt(stringOfNumbers[i]);
    }

    System.out.print("Enter the number to search:   ");
    int searchNumber = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

    int location = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
    {
        if (numbers[i][i] == searchNumber)
        {
            location = i+ 1;
        }
    }
```

thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not just add another `readLine()` statement for the next set of numbers?

Answer (score 0):

I would do somethin like this

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader("myFileName");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

while((line=br.readLine())!=null) // as  long as there are lines in the file
{
  stringOfNumbers = line.split(" ");
// other code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To read all lines of a text file you can do something like this:

```
    String path = "/path/notepad.txt";

    String stringOfNumbers[];

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader (new FileReader(path));

    ArrayList<String> listOfLines = new ArrayList<String>();
    //String lineOfNumbers = "";
    String line = "";
    String allIndexes = "";

    while ((line = br2.readLine()) != null) {
        if(!line.isEmpty()){
            listOfLines.add(line);
        }
    }

    for(String lineOfNumbers : listOfLines){
        stringOfNumbers = lineOfNumbers.split(" ");
          //stringOfNumbers = lineOfNumbers.split("\n");
        String str = lineOfNumbers.replace(","," ");
        System.out.println(str);
        System.out.print("");

        int numbers[][] = new int [stringOfNumbers.length][listOfLines.size()];

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
        {
            numbers[i][listOfLines.indexOf(lineOfNumbers)] = Integer.parseInt(stringOfNumbers[i]);
        }

        System.out.print("Enter the number to search:   ");
        int searchNumber = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        int locationI = 0;
        int locationJ = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < listOfLines.size(); j++)
                if (numbers[i][j] == searchNumber)
                {
                    locationI = i + 1;
                    locationJ = j + 1;
                    allIndexes += locationI + ":" + locationJ + " ";
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: is it possible to read the first row and second row as one? like if i search  for number 2. it will display the indexes of all 2's on the notepad?

Comment: Sure, I edited my awser so there be an allIndexes String in the form of "i:j i:j i:j ..."

Comment: the program runs but it let you search for the number twice. it search number for the first row and second row respectively.
<br>
2 3 4 5 7 2 6 2
Enter the number to search:   2
2 4 6 8 9 4 8 1
Enter the number to search:   2

Comment: Well.. remove the search from the first for loop.. Can't do it all for you.. !

Answer (score 0):

Following code will Help you save all numbers in a file to memory

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(path);

List<Integer[]> integerArList = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();

while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
String lineOfNumbers = scanner.nextLine();


        stringOfNumbers = lineOfNumbers.split(" ");
        //stringOfNumbers = lineOfNumbers.split("\n");
        String str = lineOfNumbers.replace(","," ");
        System.out.println(str);
        System.out.print("");


    Integer[] numbers = new Integer[stringOfNumbers.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
    {
        numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(stringOfNumbers[i]);
    }
    integerArList.add(numbers);
}
```

After this you can search any Integer by traversing each array in the List like this:

```
int searchMe = <get this from user>
int location=0;
boolean found=false;
for(Integer[] intAr: integerArList){
    for(int i=0;i<intAr.length;i++){
        if(intAr[i]==searchMe){
            location+=(i+1)
            found=true;
            break;
        }

    }

    if(found) break;
    location+=intAr.length;

}

System.out.println("Location of " + searchMe +" : " +(found?location:"Not Found in Data"));
```

Hope this helps.